# How to execute kusto DDL commands in Azure Data Studio?

Tags: kql, materialized-views, azure-data-studio

DDL commands in `kusto` generally start with `.` . But the SQL Editor in *Azure Data Studio* is not liking it?  Note that the parser *is* happy (no errors noted in red):

[image]

> Query failed: A recognition error occurred in the query. Query could not be parsed at '.' on line [1,1]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Azure Data Studio extension currently supports running only queries, but not control commands.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-data-studio/extensions/kusto-extension

you can run control commands from the ADX web interface (https://dataexplorer.azure.com)